# Package from a PPA not showing up

Tags: ppa

I've just added a PPA (more specifically, [this one](https://launchpad.net/~linuxgndu/+archive/ubuntu/sqlitebrowser)), but for some reason, I can't find any of the packages from it. As the link shows, there are packages there, but a search only comes the very outdated version of the program from the software centre. I'm sure there's probably something I'm doing wrong that I'm just overlooking. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu trusty main

sqlitebrowser:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.6.0~trusty1ppa2
  Version table:
     3.6.0~trusty1ppa2 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.0~beta1+ds.1-3 0
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Have you issued 'sudo apt-get update' after adding the ppa?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I have tried sudo apt-get update. 
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Has there been an error?

Comment: Not that I can see.  If I try to search for it, I just get this.

apt-cache search sqlitebrowser
sqlitebrowser - GUI editor for SQLite databases

Which is just the software centre version.

Comment: How did you add the ppa? Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/lsb-release` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks. I added the PPA the usual way.  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxgndu*.list`

Comment: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu trusty main  
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu trusty main  
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu trusty main

Comment: `apt-cache policy sqlitebrowser` ?

Comment: Add it to the question, not comments.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's my first time here. :)

Comment: It looks OK. You see version 3.6.0~trusty1ppa2.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser` will install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not install the package. PPA is connected, update has done.

Just run

```
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
```

and sqlitebrowser version 3.6.0~trusty1ppa2 will be installed.

It seems that you simply did not try to install it.

After you add a ppa, you always have to run `sudo apt-get update` to be able to install packages from it.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I did at first, but I had to uninstall it because it installed the older version, even though I had added the repository. It seems to have worked this time.

Comment: @VapourTrail because this time you ran it after `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I remember running sudo apt-get update, but maybe I wasn't paying attention (watching videos and stuff) and did it afterwards, in which case I'm sorry for the topic with an easy solution. Thanks for all your help, guys.